# How to add an HTML argument to a Rails select helper using chosen-select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to use [Multiple select with chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select) with
Rails 4.

```
<%= f.select :card_details,
  CardDetail.all.map { |cd| [cd.name, cd.id] },
               { include_blank: true },
               { class: 'chosen-select' }
%>
```

How can I add "multiple" to the HTML argument?

Right now, it renders this:

```
<select class="chosen-select" name="card[card_details]" id="card_card_details">
```

I want to add `multiple` in that line:

```
<select class="chosen-select" name="card[card_details]" multiple id="card_card_details">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `multiple: true` within the HTML options as follows:

```
<%= f.select :card_details,
  CardDetail.all.map { |cd| [cd.name, cd.id] },
               { include_blank: true },
               { class: 'chosen-select', multiple: true }
%>
```